# undefined method `type_cast' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column` used to have a method called `type_cast` which took a string and cast it "to an appropriate instance". This appears to have been removed at some point, and I can't figure out what I should do to replace it.

Here is the code that uses it:

```
  # Create a column that will be responsible for typecasting
  @column = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(attribute.to_s, options[:default], @type == 'any' ? nil : @type)

  # Typecasts the value based on the type of preference that was defined
  def type_cast(value)
    if @type == 'any'
      value
    else
      @column.type_cast(value)
    end
  end
```

I'm using Rails/ActiveRecord 4.2.10.

There's a list here: [typecast alternatives](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Column/type_cast), but it's not particularly useful, so far as I can tell.

ETA: For now, I've copied the code from the original type_cast and modified it to use it locally. But if there's a real solution, I'd prefer that.

Comment: What do you actually want to cast? Can you show a code example with more context please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column#type_cast` was removed / moved to other parts of the API, including things like `type_cast_for_database` or `type_cast_for_schema`.

You can use the `type_cast` on the connection though, like this:

```
@column = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(attribute.to_s, options[:default], @type == 'any' ? nil : @type)

# Typecasts the value based on the type of preference that was defined
def type_cast(value)
  if @type == 'any'
    value
  else
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.type_cast(value, @column) # <---- HERE
  end
end
```

You can dig in the internals at [_type_cast](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting/_type_cast) and [type_cast](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting/type_cast) if you are curious.