# undefined method `type_cast' for ActiveRecord and stacklevel too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following method:

```
def parent_item_id=(item_id)
  if new_record?
    self[:parent_item_id] = item_id
  elsif self[:parent_item_id] != self.class.columns_hash['parent_item_id'].type_cast(item_id)
    remove_from_list
    self[:parent_item_id] = item_id
  end
end
```

Which gives me the error:

```
undefined method `type_cast' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column>
```

So I applied what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884908/undefined-method-type-cast-for-activerecordconnectionadapterscolumn-no):

```
def parent_item_id=(item_id)
  if new_record?
    self[:parent_item_id] = item_id
  # CHANGES IN THE LINE BELOW:
  elsif self[:parent_item_id] != ActiveRecord::Base.connection.type_cast(item_id, self.class.columns_hash['parent_item_id']) # <-- THIS
    remove_from_list
    self[:parent_item_id] = item_id
  end
end
```

but then I get:

```
SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
```

I just upgraded to rails 5.0.7 and ruby 2.5.1

Backtrace:

```
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/scoping.rb:79:in `value_for'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/per_thread_registry.rb:53:in `value_for'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/scoping.rb:14:in `current_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:25:in `all'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:124:in `target_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:86:in `scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:429:in `scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:348:in `empty?'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:50:in `empty?'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:359:in `any?'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:846:in `any?'
 # ./app/models/report_section.rb:16:in `parent_sections_cannot_have_parents'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:547:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `catch'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `block in default_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in `block in halting'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.7/lib/active_model/validations.rb:408:in `run_validations!'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.7/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `block in run_validations!'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.7/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `run_validations!'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.7/lib/active_model/validations.rb:338:in `valid?'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:65:in `valid?'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:82:in `perform_validations'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block (2 levels) in save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:230:in `transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:217:in `set_list_position'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:128:in `remove_from_list'
 # ./app/models/report_section.rb:29:in `parent_report_section_id='
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `block in check_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `check_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:770:in `block (2 levels) in deprecated_false_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `catch'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `block in deprecated_false_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_update_callbacks'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_update_record'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:81:in `_update_record'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:548:in `create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `block in create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_save_callbacks'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:129:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block (2 levels) in save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:230:in `transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:217:in `set_list_position'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:128:in `remove_from_list'
 # ./app/models/report_section.rb:29:in `parent_report_section_id='
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `block in check_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `check_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:770:in `block (2 levels) in deprecated_false_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `catch'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `block in deprecated_false_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_update_callbacks'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_update_record'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:81:in `_update_record'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:548:in `create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `block in create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_save_callbacks'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:129:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block (2 levels) in save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:230:in `transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:217:in `set_list_position'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:128:in `remove_from_list'
 # ./app/models/report_section.rb:29:in `parent_report_section_id='
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `block in check_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `check_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:770:in `block (2 levels) in deprecated_false_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `catch'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `block in deprecated_false_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_update_callbacks'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_update_record'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:81:in `_update_record'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:548:in `create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `block in create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_save_callbacks'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:129:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block (2 levels) in save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:230:in `transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:217:in `set_list_position'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:128:in `remove_from_list'
 # ./app/models/report_section.rb:29:in `parent_report_section_id='
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `block in check_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `check_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:770:in `block (2 levels) in deprecated_false_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `catch'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `block in deprecated_false_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_update_callbacks'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_update_record'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:81:in `_update_record'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:548:in `create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `block in create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_save_callbacks'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `create_or_update'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:129:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block (2 levels) in save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:230:in `transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:217:in `set_list_position'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:128:in `remove_from_list'
 # ./app/models/report_section.rb:29:in `parent_report_section_id='
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `block in check_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.16/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:466:in `check_scope'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:770:in `block (2 levels) in deprecated_false_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `catch'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `block in deprecated_false_terminator'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-
```

Thanks

Comment: Does `remove_from_list` end up saying `self.parent_item_id = nil`? Because that would make an infinite loop.

Comment: @Nate ok, yes. I removed it and that error dissappears. This is a legacy project, and I can't seem to find the method implemented anywhere. Seems to be part of the act_as_list gem. Before upgrading rails, the test didn't fail. Any thoughts on how to implement it?

Comment: If you add a backtrace of the error to your post, it would help with debugging.

Comment: @Nate I've added the backtrace